# Problem with derived dummy type, containing allocatable arrays

Tags: fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation, intel-fortran

I have a problem with a subroutine, using a derived type as dummy argument, that in turn, contains allocatable arrays.
Here my piece of code:

```
Subroutine SubA( vf, kf)
type vfType
real*8, dimension(dim1) :: var_1
real*8, dimension(dim1) :: var_2
... hundred more
end type
type (vfType), intent(inout) :: vf
...
call SubB(vf, kf, dim_par)
...
```

The definition of SubB is:

```
Subroutine SubB(vf, kf, dim_par)
type vfType
real*8, allocatable, dimension(:) :: var_1
real*8, allocatable, dimension(:) :: var_2
... hundred more
end type
type (vfType), intent(inout) :: vf
include 'allocator.fi'
```

!**the next piece of code is in the allocator include file**

```
if (.not.allocated(vf%var_1)) allocate(vf%var_1(dim_par%dim1))
if (.not.allocated(vf%var_2)) allocate(vf%var_2(dim_par%dim1))
...hundred more
```

I pass the dimension of the arrays in another derived, called dim_par

What is puzzling me is that, in runtime, the code is capable of allocate certain number of arrays but not all, I've tried several simplified versions of the code and always crashes after allocating 20 variables (no matter what they are).
Even more, if a print:

```
allocated(vf%var_21)
```

I get FALSE, but when the line:

```
if (.not.allocated(vf%var_21)) allocate(vf%var_21(dim_par%dim1))
```

is executed right after, an error of already allocated array is thrown, therefore the code, after deciding that the array is NOT allocated, is not capable of allocating it, because is already allocated.
At this point, it is driving me crazy, so I would appreciate some kind of light.

I'm using Intel Fortran

Thx in advance

Comment: We need a [mre] to give you an answer. The derived types `vfType` in `subA` and `vfType` in `subB` are not the same, so all manner of things can go wrong when you do `call subB(vf)` in `subA` through the mis-match of types. We're just guessing which particular thing is going wrong unless you show us a complete example.

Comment: The limited piece of code you are showing is definitely illegal, as the type of the dummy argument `vf` in `SubB(...)`is different from the type of the actual argument `vf` in `call SubB(...)`. Hence no surprise if things go wrong during the execution.

Comment: Thank you both!
Now I have a more clear idea

Comment: Just one more comment, types vfType in SubA and SubB are of course different, what I'm trying to do in SubB, is to make vfType of the same shape as in SubA (same array members, same dimensions), dinamically, I don't know wether this is possible or not. The reason is that at compilation time of SubB, I don't know the sizes of the arrays, and they are too many to use a parametrized derived type...

Comment: Sorry, I'm here again: what about this? To declare arrays in vfType of subA as allocatable, allocate them (I know the sizes), and keep vfType in subB as it currently is...

Comment: It doesn't work, when I try to allocate the 21st element of vfType in SubA, I get exactly the same runtime error, this time in SubA, hmmm, sounds really weird!!!

Comment: Are you using a `Module`?

Comment: I think, I know understand, sorry I didn't provide you with all the information. Actually there are three calling levels, from Sub1 -> SubA -> SubB. In Sub1 the derived type vf is equivalenced with a DB "mirror", that is actually a common block. I think that's driving crazy the program. I know use of commons is an old fashion style, but this code is a kind of mixture between old and new, thanks for all your help!

Comment: You have to provide each subroutine with *exactly* the same declaration of your derived type - not just the same text repeated in each routine (even by a include file) but the *same piece of code*. This is easiest done using a module, which if you also stick the subroutines also in the Module will probably address any issues with argument passing. In fact I strongly recommend *always* use modules for routines, it will save you much grief in the long run. Oh, and never use real*8, it is not standard, has never been standard, and might not do what you think. Look into Fortran `kind`s.

Comment: (Yes, there is at least one other way, namely Sequence, but use of modules is by far the best)

Comment: Thank you Ian, I'll take your coment into account for the future... This is the second time I post a question, I appreciate all your help guys!